# Macro to Find and Replace Field Names

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find and replace hundreds of misnamed field names (cell names) in a large excel financial model. I'm trying to build this macro subroutine to find a given field name and replace it with the correct field name.

```
Sub FindReplaceFieldName()

Dim orgFieldName As String
Dim replFieldName As String

orgFieldName = "CAN"
replFieldName = "Canada"

Application.Goto Reference:=orgFieldName

With ActiveWorkbook.names(orgFieldName)
    .Name = replFieldName
    .RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!(" & activeCell.row & ";" & activeCell.Column &")".Comment = ""
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

The field name is found and replaced, but a Runtime error 1004 is thrown here

> "=Sheet1!(" & activeCell.row & ";" & activeCell.Column & 
>    ")"

"The formula you typed contains an error." and so on.

I'm not familiar with VBA syntax, so a 2nd pair of experienced eyes would be helpful.

SOLVED: The correct syntax should be

```
.RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R" & activeCell.row & "C" & activeCell.Column & ""
```

Comment: Is there error trigged by having two equal operators on that line?  RefersToR1C1 = "sheet1"... = "".     Seems a bit funny to me

Comment: Use `","` in place of `";"` and test. In VBA you don't need to use semi-colon.

Comment: Did you try my solution below? Not sure why you are touching the RefersTo if it is the names that need changing.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for your suggestion. But my error was how I was building the String. See the "Solved" comment.

Comment: I saw that but aren't you changing the names? The refers to remains the same doesn't it? The cells don't move?

Comment: @QHarr sorry, I'm not sure what you are talking about. I may be using RefersToR1C1 wrong. But I found this method works for changing the fieldName for cells.

Comment: You only want to change the names right? So Can to Canada etc..... the cell remains the same..so if Can was A1 then Canada is A1? Is that correct? Only the name changes?

Comment: @QHarr yes. The cell does not move or change. Only the fieldName changes.

Ahhh - I think I see what your code is doing. That looks less clumsy. I'll try it.

Comment: It should be more efficient and ties nicely with being able to keep mapping of what was to what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive me if wrong, but are you not approaching this sideways? You want to change the existing names not amend the locations; ***Ergo***, use a mapping to rename the existing.

For example, use a **dictionary** to rename (you could use other structures); I wanted to leverage the `.Exists` of a dictionary so only attempted valid substitutions. You could even loop a range in the sheet to populate your dictionary. Or read the range straight into an array and dump the array into the dictionary as key/values.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RenameNamedRanges()

    Dim currName As Name
    Dim replaceDict As Object
    Set replaceDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    replaceDict.Add "CAN", "Canada"
    replaceDict.Add "FR", "France"
    replaceDict.Add "DE", "Deutschland"

    For Each currName In ThisWorkbook.Names

        If replaceDict.Exists(currName.Name) Then

            currName.Name = replaceDict(currName.Name)

        End If

    Next currName

End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot issues like this, where you're building a string to be used elsewhere, troubleshoot by looking at the problem string just before the error is caused.

In this case, you could add a line just before the line where you get the error:

```
Debug.Print "=Sheet1!(" & activeCell.row & ";" & activeCell.Column & ")"
```

...then, when you run your code and get the error, go to the Immediate Window  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and see what *Excel thinks* you mean.

Are you able to see your error now?

---

That being said, you must have posted your code incorrectly, since I can't get it to run at all (to get an Error 1004) since this line is wonky:

```
.RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!(" & activeCell.row & ";" & activeCell.Column &")".Comment = ""
```

If I replace the row and column *numbers* you're trying to insert with 1234 then it would read:

```
.RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!(1234;1234)".Comment = ""
```

I can't give an absolute solution without knowing more about what you're trying to do, but obviously that is an invalid command (and likely not what you intended).

---

Note that `ActiveCell.Row` and `ActiveCell.Column` both return *numbers*, and that `Sheet1!(1,1)` is not how we refer to a cell in Excel.

Comment: .RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R" & activeCell.row & "C" & activeCell.Column & ""

is want was needed.